# excel 2013 vba range names count not working

Tags: excel, excel-2013, named-ranges, vba

I am using Excel 2013 and cannot get the count nor a listing of range names. I can open the Names Manager dialog box and the names and ranges are listed. I added the names (List1,List2, and List3) to the workbook using VBA (Set rngTable = c.CurrentRegion.ListObjects.Add). I can iterate through the named ranges by using "List" &  intCounter to get the ranges associated with each list. But I cannot get the number of names nor a list of names.

I tried following code in Excel 2013 and 2007 and when execution gets to the line ***For i = 1 To namedRanges.Count*** it returns zero (0). What can I do to get the number of named ranges in the workbook and list the names of the named ranges?  Your help is greatly appreciated!

Private Sub Something()

```
Dim namedRanges As Names
Set namedRanges = ActiveSheet.Names

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = Sheet3
targetSheet.Cells.Clear

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To namedRanges.Count
    targetSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = namedRanges(i).Name
    targetSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = namedRanges(i).RefersToRange.Address
Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Are your named ranges scoped to the worksheet, or the workbook? If they're not limited to a single worksheet, you'll need to reference the workbook.Names collection instead.

```
Set namedRanges = ActiveWorkbook.Names
```

Comment: I solved the problem.  When I added the names to the workbook they were added as list objects.  I revised the code to select the current region and add a name for that range area.  Now the named ranges can be counted and listed in using the above coding. Can't be done when the name is a list object.  Thanks for your response Werrf!